# Facing issue while overriding core file

Tags: magento2

Override below file in custom extension

1. Core module path: vendor/amasty/module-gift-card-account/view/adminhtml/ui_component/amgcard_account_formnew.xml
2. Custom extension path: app/code/Ghanda/GiftCardAccount/view/adminhtml/ui_component/amgcard_account_formnew.xml

I need to change balance field validation from 'validate-digits' to 'validate-number'. File properly overriding but validation calling from the core module not the overriden file.

Comment: I think you should override on custom theme.

Comment: Can you please give exact path to override into custom theme?